# Bug or virus? Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed

Tags: initramfs

after I install and run the game https://boogiedowntech.itch.io/skies, the computer froze, the terminal did not open with a keyboard shortcut, when closing the notebook it did not turn off etc.

I managed to shut down the computer, but when I turn on, it appears to me:

```
0.561003] Initramfs unpacking failed: 
Decoding failed save up waiting for root file system device. 
Common problems: - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline) - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?) 
Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; Is /dev) 
ALERT! UUID=65bfe664-17d9-4b5c-b2b5-6e4f 1650a27e does not exist. 
Dropping to a shell! 
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.3) built-in shell (ash) 
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands. 
(initramfs)
```

Is this malware or is it just a bug?

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  You said it froze, were you able to shutdown cleanly using SysRq keys?  If you didn't cleanly shutdown the laptop, did you `fsck` (*file-system check*) your partition(s)?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04, I hung up by pressing the on/off button for about 20s (sorry I don't know its name). I didn't check the partitions.

Comment: I would use keyboard commands to shutdown the machine cleanly (eg. SysRq keys which go direct from keyboard to linux kernel, meaning they work even if GUI/desktop/user-applications are frozen). If you're stuck and forget the commands, I'd suggest searching "magic sysrq" on a phone & look at the wikipedia page; it's as good as any to remind you of commands.  After unclean shutdown (power cutoff), I'd boot a *live* system & check your file-systems (ie. `fsck`) then I'd hope system boots normally when next tried.  (note: on some modern (smaller) keyboards; Sysrq key may require multiple keys)

Comment: Thanks, i will follow your tips tomorrow and anything i say here!